# How to add a preceding '0' to days and months less than 10

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, date

I am having some issues displaying data from my backend API because the incoming dates are formatted incorrectly.

Currently, day and month numbers are entered without a preceding '0' if they are less than 10. For example, `9` should be `09`

All incoming dates are in this format: `year/month/day`.

How can I transform the dates to a format with preceding zeros for numbers less than 10?

My current code:

```js
let date = '2021/1/31';

const addZeros = (date) => {
  const year = date.split('/')[0];
  const month = date.split('/')[1];
  const day = date.split('/')[2];

  return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
};

console.log(addZeros(date));
```

Tests:

`2021/9/14` -->  `2021/09/14`

`2021/1/7` -->  `2021/01/07`

`2021/10/17` -->  `2021/10/17`

Comment: Can you please post any code you have tried so far?

Comment: Are data in string format?

Comment: @decpk, Yes! all dates are in string format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```js
function convertDate(str) {
  return str
    .split("/")
    .map((s) => (s < 10 ? `0${s}` : s))
    .join("/");
}

console.log(convertDate("2021/9/14")); //--> 2021/09/14
console.log(convertDate("2021/1/7")); //--> 2021/01/07
console.log(convertDate("2021/10/17")); //--> 2021/10/17
```

Comment: The use of *parseInt* is redundant, the less than operator will coerce the string to number anyway. The map function could be `.map(n => (n < 10? '0' : '') + n)`. :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
const addZeros = (date) => {
  let [year, month, day] = date.split('/');
  month = month.length == 1 ? `0${month}` : month; 
  day = day.length == 1 ? `0${day}` : day; 

  return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
};


const test = (date, formatDate) => {
  if ( addZeros(date) == formatDate )
    console.log("Success!")
  else
    console.log(`Error: Expected: ${formatDate}, Receive: addZeros(date)`)
}

test('2021/1/31', '2021-01-31')
test('2021/11/1', '2021-11-01')
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this simple method to add leading zeros:

```
function leadingZeros(n, digitsneeded)
{
 return ("00000000000" + n).substr(-digitsneeded)
}

// leadingzeros(3, 2) is "03"
// leadingzeros(12, 5) is "00012"
// leadingzeros(1234, 3) is "234" -- Be careful!
```

There is no need to check whether you already have the right number of digits.  (However, it will truncate a "too big" number, so watch out for that.)